# Can I use LoDash to map a large json object (from REST service) to a smaller object?

Tags: javascript, json, underscore.js, lodash

I am receiving a list of tweets (from a REST service) which is a really big list of many properties but I am only interested in a few properties in each item in the collection that is returned.

What is the best way of mapping this to a smaller object? Would Lodash help here?

Would I just iterate over it and create many new object?

Comment: What type of object is it? Sounds like it would be an array if it is a list. If so, why not use the native [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method?

Comment: Also, just a note about JSON vs objects: JSON is a string and not an object hence its abbreviation of **J**ava**S**cript **O**bject **N**otation. If what you have can already be accessed as an object then it is colloquially referred to as a POJO or **P**lain **O**ld **J**ava**S**cript **O**bject. They are different. The former is a data exchange format similar to YAML or XML while the latter is an actual object with properties and values.

Comment: If you already have the object loaded in memory, why do you want to go through the trouble of reducing it? Is it to save memory? Will this object be retained or will it be discarded once used? If it's not retained, it might not be worth the trouble. And is the difference in size between the base object and the stripped object so significant that it would warrant it, even if it was to be retained?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you've already created an Array of the large tweet Objects from your JSON (String), there is in fact a underscore/lodash function for creating Objects with subsets of properties. You're after [_.pick](https://lodash.com/docs#pick).

Basically, you'd do something along the lines of:

```
var importantParams = ["id", "user", "text", "created_at"];

var smallerObjArray = _.map(largerObjArray, function(largeObj){
    return _.pick(largeObj, importantParams);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Definitely, lodash can really be useful while finding a property in a big json. It has many useful methods to manage the collections. pluck is my favorite.

Iterating over that big object is a tedious job. It can be done, but lodash is the easy and smart way to go :)